# Cpanel Licence Update Failed Due To Improper Server Configuration

Tags: centos, cpanel

I installed my new server and I installed trial cpanel. But now It says I have no licencse and when I'm trying to update it gives me this error.

Error message:
License update failed due to improper server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cpanel licence needs, FQDN for licence update.

Open ssh and type  " **hostname your FQDN** " , now you can update your licence

/usr/local/cpanel/cpkeyclt